# Create spec for model with joins associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

how can I do a spec for a model that calls the joins method
I have this code but not working i get errors for the method joins

```
def applicants_income_average
  users.joins(:financial_data).sum(:net_income_verified) /
  users.joins(:financial_data).where("financial_data.
    net_income_verified IS NOT NULL").size
end

context "#applicants_income_average" do
  before do
    user_a.build_financial_data(net_income_verified: 12_000)
    user_b.build_financial_data(net_income_verified: 13_000)

    allow(whitelabel).to receive(:users).and_return([user_a, user_b])
    allow(user_a).to receive(:join).and_return(user_a.financial_data)
    allow(user_b).to receive(:join).and_return(user_b.financial_data)
  end

  it "Should return 12_500" do
    expect(whitelabel.applicants_income_average).to eql(12_500)
  end
end
```

Comment: I don't think you should really get into stubbing the active record methods ... you should test input/output only, when possible.

Comment: Stubbing out ActiveRecord makes perfect sense. The Rails core team has already tested it. Always assume your framework will do what it says. Just test the code that you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Admittedly, it may be easier to test ActiveRecord through the database than it is to mock, thanks to ActiveRecord's method chaining. But, if you can put up with the chained `allow` statements, your tests will be SOOOO much faster if you mock ActiveRecord. Plus, you won't be testing something that has already been thoroughly tested by the Rails core team.

Here's how I would approach the problem above. I annotated some assumptions and modifications I made to the code. Hope it helps!

```
class Whitelabel
  # I modified this for readability, but in the process discovered
  # that the same query could probably be used for both the numerator
  # and the denominator.
  def applicants_income_average
    sum_of_verified_net_income / count_of_users_with_verified_net_income
  end

  private

  def sum_of_verified_net_income
    users_with_verified_net_income.sum(:net_income_verified)
  end

  def count_of_users_with_verified_net_income
    users_with_verified_net_income.size
  end

  # Using a single query and memoizing the results will improve performance
  # This will also make it easier to test since we'll only call it once
  def users_with_verified_net_income
    @users_with_verified_net_income ||= do
      users
        .joins(:financial_data)
        .where('financial_data.net_income_verified IS NOT NULL')
    end
  end

  # I'm assuming this method must exist, given that the  
  # implementation of applicants_income_average referenced it
  def users
    User.where('some criteria')
  end
end

describe Whitelabel do
  subject(:whitelabel) { described_class.new }

  describe '#applicants_income_average' do
    subject(:applicants_income_average) { whitelabel.applicants_income_average }

    let(:users) { instance_double('users') }
    let(:users_with_financial_data) { instance_double('users_with_financial_data') }
    let(:users_with_verified_net_income) do
      instance_double('users_with_verified_net_income', sum: sum, size: size )
    end
    let(:sum) { 25000 }
    let(:size) { 2 }
    let(:average) { sum / size }

    before do
      allow(User).to receive(:where).and_return(users)
      allow(users).to receive(:joins).and_return(users_with_financial_data)
      allow(users_with_financial_data)
        .to receive(:where)
        .and_return(users_with_verified_net_income)
    end

    it 'selects the correct users' do
      applicants_income_average

      expect(User).to have_received(:where).with('some criteria')
    end

    it 'joins with financial data model' do
      applicants_income_average

      expect(users).to have_received(:joins).with(:financial_data)
    end

    it 'selects the users with verified net income' do
      applicants_income_average

      expect(users_with_financial_data)
        .to have_received(:where)
        .with('financial_data.net_income_verified IS NOT NULL')
    end

    it 'calculates average' do
      expect(applicants_income_average).to eq(average)
    end
  end
end
```